# Validation backend with get Google Token on android

Tags: android, google-api-client

I have a problem when I try get Google token in android to Balidation backend. I create Web Application Client Id (I use http://localhost in url paths), Android Client Id, and use this code:

```
public class GoogleOAuthTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

private static final String TAG = GoogleOAuthTask.class.getSimpleName();
Activity mActivity;
String mEmail;

private final static String SCOPE = "audience:server:client_id:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAAAAAXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com";

public GoogleOAuthTask(Activity activity, String email) {
    this.mActivity = activity;
    this.mEmail = name;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String accountName = "myRandomValidEmail@gmail.com";
    Account account = new Account(accountName, GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    String scopes = "audience:server:client_id:XXXXXASASXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"; // This is my Web Application Client Id
    try {
        return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, account, scopes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving ID token.", e);
        return null;
    } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving ID token.", e);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

My problem is:

**When I call GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, account, scopes) the code no continue , i.e, method never end.**

I'm waiting

More informations:

I use .android/debug.keystore to generate SHA-1 hash
I use http://localhost in Javascript Origins
I use http://localhost/MyWebService in Redirect URI.
This line appears in logcat:

```
Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Thread pool in AsyncTask.